# Make only part of flatlist header sticky

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist with two components on top of it that need to scroll the flatlist.  The obvious fix is to make a header component which includes both components.  The problem is i only want the second component to be sticky.  I can make both headers sticky with

```
stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
```

however since both components are wrapped to make them the header i cant use stickyHeaderIndices to make it sticky.

Comment: I think you have to set  ```position: 'absolute'``` to the sticky button

Comment: Have you ever solved out this issue?

Comment: i dont think i did